# Memchached. Куда сохраняются данные?

Tags: php, linux

Добрый день. Всех с днем книги.

**[Q]** Хотелось бы узнать, где хранит свои данные memcache, который для php?

Я начал им активно пользоваться, и хотелось бы узнать побольше о нем.
Мне кажется, эти данные хранятся в оперативной памяти, но тогда это не совсем хорошо, или же мне придется искать новые пути кэширования данных.

Comment: Чем для вас хранение в оперативной памяти, "не хорошо"?

Comment: 1. Не желательно хранить большие объемы данных.
2. И, оперативная память имеет не очень большие объемы данных.

Для кэширования общей информации, наверное, хорошо, а для индивидуальной, уже не пойдет (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данные хранятся в оперативной памяти. Собственно, название как-бы намекает об этом. Memcached не предназначен для хранения данных, потому что memcached - это кэш - т.е., система, временного хранения данных(кэша). Ни в коем случае не храните данные только в memcache, вместо этого, складывайте туда только часто используемые данные, например, для того, чтобы разгрузить сервер БД от однотипных запросов.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я понял, там можно хранить небольшие объемы данных, которые больше всего используются всеми или почти всеми пользователями. А где кэшировать другую (более объемную) инфу? в БД?

Comment: @frops, смотря какая "инфа".

Comment: Например, данные, для выборки которых приходится использовать сложные SQL-запросы или ресурсоемкие элементы скриптов.

Comment: Редко меняющиеся данные проще сохранить в БД, и положить в кэш, и при каждом запросе проверять наличие этих данных в кэше. Если есть - берем из кэша, если нету - запрашиваем из бд.

Comment: Как понять "сохранить в БД, и положить в кэш"? То есть создать специальную табличку в БД, куда писать данные, и потом оттуда их вынимать?

Comment: Именно так. Но нужно профилировать, что получается производительней: проверка/выборка из кэша или создание данных с нуля.